# Demonstration of a singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

This is a simple demonstration of a singly linked list, from my class work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
struct node
{
    int          info;
    struct node *link;
};

typedef struct node* NODE;

NODE main()
{
    NODE first = NULL;
    int  item, choice;

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("1.INSERT AT FRONT\n2.DISPLAY\n3.QUIT\n\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            printf("\nEnter the item to be inserted:");
            scanf("%d", &item);

            first = insert_front(item,first);
            break;

            case 2:
            display(first);
            break;

            case 3:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

NODE getnode()
{
    NODE x;

    x = (NODE) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(x == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    return x;
}

int insert_front(int item, NODE first)
{
    NODE temp;
    temp = getnode();
    temp->info = item;
    temp->link = first;
    return temp;
}

void display(NODE first)
{
    NODE temp;

    if(first == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty");
        return;
    }

    printf("\nThe contents are: ");

    temp = first;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->info);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

As you can see, this code demonstrates the working of a linked list. How can this program more smaller, better, more professional and much more good? If you were given a chance to modify this program, how would you do it? I wanna know how to think and how to train myself to modify programs like these. And as you see, I have learned most of C. I referred to and learned C from K.N Kings *The C programming language: A modern approach* and *Computer science: A structured approach using C* and data structures from *Data structures using C* by Tenenbaum.

Now I have stretched my legs in learning C what can I do to create application that might be useful to me or to others. Say I want to create a small game like "snake" or create a small application that my father might use to do his business.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C-guru at all but I believe I can give you a few advices to improve your code:

1. Review your included libraries. Do you really need all those ones? Nope. <del>Chuck Testa</del> You only use `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`.
2. `main()` should return `int` and you specify it actually returns `NODE`... but it isn't returning nothing at all! Double fail x( So... `int main() { return 0; }` FTW
3. Naming consistency. You have written `getnode()` and `insert_front()`. You can name your members whatever you want (`getnode()`, `getNode()`, `get_node()`) but keep the patter for all of them (`insertfront()`, `insertFront()`, `insert_front()`). IMO, underscores are much C-style.
4. Blank lines. Avoid inserting blank lines. They don't clarify the reading of your code, instead of that they expand your code unnecessarily. You can insert blank lines between your function definitions. This helps to delimit and group your functions and eases their location.
5. What if I type `4` in your menu? The golden rule in programming is: *Users provide bad inputs*. So you always must to validate inputs. Don't matter if it seems trivial. **Always**.
6. And for last and getting a bit cranky, you can get a temp node in one step within `insert_front()`:

   ```
   NODE temp = get_node(); // I've changed `getnode()` name for you. You are welcome.
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Some more (append to jackflash's answer!):

1. The `printf()` function has to scan the format string, and is therefore less efficient than `puts()`. In a similar way, `printf("\n");` could be `puts("\n");` but really should be `putchar('\n');`.
2. It's hard to use `scanf()` while also implementing proper error handling. It's impossible to use "scanf()" properly without checking its ("number of successful assignments") returned value. Failure to check the return value is always a bug.
3. Your `switch(choice)` needs a `default: puts("Bad option!\n");`.
4. The `typedef struct node* NODE;` should probably be `typedef struct node NODE;` instead (with corresponding changes everywhere to suit). This makes it much easier for programmers to see when something is a pointer and when it's not. For example, consider `int foo(NODE *destNode, NODE srcNode);` where it's easy to see what is happening; and compare it to `int foo(NODE destNode, Um?? );` where the first parameter looks like "pass by value".
5. `getnode()` doesn't get/find a node, but creates a node instead. It should be named appropriately (e.g. `create_node()`).
6. `getnode()` could/should initialise the structure. E.g. `NODE *create_node(int info) { ...; x->link = NULL; x->info = info; return x; }`.
7. `int insert_front()` is buggy, because it returns a `pointer to struct node` and doesn't return an `int`. Your compiler should have complained loudly about this bug.
8. `insert_front()` could/should insert a previously created node, instead of mixing different operations ("create" and "insert"). Basically it'd be `NODE *insert_front(NODE *newNode, NODE *firstNode)` or perhaps `void insert_front(NODE **firstNode, NODE *newNode)`.

Comment: Very good point!

Comment: `puts` outputs its own `\n`, IIRC.  So, `puts("");`?

Comment: `putchar('\n')` if you only want to output one character (to avoid the extra overhead of a pointless loop that searches for a string terminator). `fputs("string", stdout);` if you want to output a string without the newline. `puts("string");` if you want to output a string with a newline. `printf()` if you can't use any other option.

Answer (score 2):

Siddarth, here are some extra points to add to those from @JackFlash and @Brendan.

- Turn on more compiler warnings, for example with gcc I use the following:
      -Wall
  -Wextra
  -Wshadow
  -Wstrict-prototypes 
  -Wmissing-prototypes
  -Wundef
  -Wunreachable-code
  -Wunused
  -Wcast-qual
- With compiler warnings enabled you will get some warnings from your code because of missing prototypes.
  You have no prototypes for functions.  There are two options: either define
  all functions before (above) where they are used; or declare prototypes for
  functions that are used before they are defined.  I usually take the former
  approach which means that `main()` is always defined at the end of the file.
- All functions, except `main()` that are used only within the file where they
  are defined should be defined as 'static': `static void display(NODE first)`
- In a linked list, the pointer to the next node is perhaps more logically called `next`
- `main()` has the prototype `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`.
- Functions that take no parameters should have a 'void' parameter list, eg
  `static NODE get_node(void) {...}`
- As stated by others, don't define pointer types.
- Upper case identifiers are normally reserved for preprocessor constants
  (defined with `#define`).  For your node type, use `node` or perhaps `Node`,
  but not `NODE`.
- `getnode` (better get_node), being so small, is sensible as a separate function only if it is
  to be used more than once. In your code it is not, but I guess it might be
  if you added an `insert_end` to your existing `insert_front`.  Otherwise I
  would rename `insert_front` to `insert` and integrate the `malloc` there.
- the value returned from `malloc` should not be cast.
- 'x' is a poor choice of name for a 'node'.  'n' would make more sense -
  whatever you choose, be consistent.  In `display` you use `temp`.
- combine the memory allocation and the declatation of the variable to hold the
  pointer: `node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));`
- Put a space after keywords (`if`, `else`, `while`, `for` etc) (my personal preference)
- Print errors to `stderr` not `stdout`.  Use `perror` where you can (as in
  failure of `malloc`): `perror("malloc");`
- `exit` should use `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`
- `insert_front` should return a `node *` (or '`Node *`)
- in `display` your `while` loop could perhaps be done as a `for`

  ```
  for (node *n = first; n != 0; n = n->link) 
  {
      printf("%d ", n->info);
  }
  ```